# Printing a Windows Form fit to an A4 Paper

Tags: c#, winforms

I have used the following code to print out a 810 by 788 Windows Form:

```
private void bunifuFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bunifuFlatButton2.Hide();

        PaperSize ps = new PaperSize("custom", 828, 750);
        ps.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4;


        Graphics graph = CreateGraphics();
        bmp = new Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height, graph);
         graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;

        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();

        bunifuFlatButton2.Show();

    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.X;
        int y = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Y;
        int width = 810;
        int height = 750;

        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height);

        this.DrawToBitmap(img, bounds);
        Point p = new Point(-8, -50);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p);

    }
```

The problem is it doesn't cover the whole A4 paper and only part of the paper is covered. Is there a way to make the form cover the whole A4 paper?

Comment: Do you want to STRETCH your form and lose aspect ratio so that it covers the paper?

Comment: @Idle_Mind yes exactly i want to stretch it so it covers the whole paper

Comment: DrawImage() has a bunch of overloads, use a Rectangle to give the desired size of the image.  And yes, it is supposed to look that bad.